# Falha ao copiar todo um diretório e seus arquivos

Tags: java, arquivo

Estou precisando copiar todo um diretório que contem arquivos dentro usando o Java `NIO2` com `FileChannels`. Porem só consigo fazer a cópia dos arquivos dentro do diretório.

Segue o código que estou usando para copiar os arquivos:

```
public static void copiaDestino(File destino, File origem) throws IOException{

    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(origem).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(destino).getChannel();
    try{
        int maxCont = (64 * 1024 * 1024) - (32 * 1024);
        long size = inChannel.size();
        long position = 0;

        while (position < size){
            position += inChannel.transferTo(position, size, outChannel);
        }
        }finally{
            if(inChannel != null){
                inChannel.close();
            }
            if(outChannel != null){
                outChannel.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Então como ainda estou testando eu crio duas variáveis do tipo File e passo os caminhos (Origem/Destino). Ao executar o código passando o diretório e não o nome do arquivo da um erro (Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Novapasta (Acesso negado))

Comment: Então o caminho ate encontra quando eu coloco dentro do " C: " porem se eu quiser copiar por exemplo "C:\teste" também da o mesmo erro, mas se eu adicionar:

 File origem = new File("C:\\Novapasta\\server.sql");
 File destino = new File("C:\\t");

Ele cria um arquivo com o nome de " t " em "C:"

Comment: Peço desculpas estou começando agora aqui. Mas o que estou tentando fazer é copiar o diretório "C:\Nova Pasta" para "C:\Nova Pasta2", tenho o método acima pra fazer a cópia tanto do diretório quanto dos arquivos contido nele. Na main eu instancio 2 variáveis do tipo File e passo origem e destino, se eu deixar assim como eu disse acima origem e destino ele da acesso negado na pasta de origem e se eu apontar um arquivo dentro da pasta de origem o erro de acesso negado acontece no caminho de destino, caso o caminho de origem nao exista então ele cria um arquivo e nao copia o citado na origem

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Este método só copia arquivos e não diretórios.

Pelos comentários parece estar funcionando quando usado corretamente. Eu notei que tem uma inversão de parâmetros que faz o seu uso não ser tão intuitivo e provavelmente está gerando erros porque ele está fazendo o contrário do que pensa.

Por falta de informações não posso ajudar mais que isto.

```
//note a inversão dos parâmetros aqui
public static void copiaDestino(File origem, File destino) throws IOException{

    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(origem).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(destino).getChannel();
    try{
    int maxCont = (64 * 1024 * 1024) - (32 * 1024);
    long size = inChannel.size();
    long position = 0;

    while (position < size){
        position += inChannel.transferTo(position, size, outChannel);
    }
    }finally{
    if(inChannel != null){
        inChannel.close();
    }
    if(outChannel != null){
        outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

No `main()`:

```
try {
    File origem = new File("C:\\Novapasta\\server.sql");
    File destino = new File("C:\\t");
    copiaDestino(origem, destino)
} catch (Exception ex) { //isto só é útil aqui porque é o main
    System.out.println("Deu erro");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/InvertParamenter.java).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda... Mas o erro que estava dando de acesso negado era porque eu estava passando um arquivo como origem e um diretório como destino... ficaria assim:

File origem = new File("C:\\Novapasta\\server.sql");
File destino = new File("C:\\t\\cópia.sql");

Só assim ele copiou. Obrigado e fica ai pra caso alguém esteja com a mesma dificuldade.